# How to retrieve amount Stripe credited to my account for an order

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's payments API with their Java library. Our Stripe account is denominated in EUR.

If we charge a customer an amount in USD, and the charge is successful, the charge is credited to our account in the EUR equivalent.

How can we use the Stripe API to find out this EUR amount immediately after the order was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [retrieve the balance_transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance_transaction) associated with the charge, using the charge's [`balance_transaction`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-balance_transaction) attribute.

The converted amount will be available in the balance_transaction's [`amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#balance_transaction_object-amount) attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for